# bazel buid <app-to-build>:"Configurable attribute "actual" doesn't match this configuration"

Tags: bazel, ppc64le

I'm setting up a ppc64le server and I need to install bazel 0.23.* on it. I compiled bazel for this architecture but it does not work properly.

I'm trying to install an app (ONOS) on an Ubuntu 18.04 ppc64le server. It's not supported for this architecture so I need to build it from source using bazel (as ONOS documentation explains). I installed bazel version 0.23.0 from a binary already compiled for ppc64le architecture. 
Now i tried to build the app using bazel (bazel build onos) but it shows an error related to "JDK environment"

```
root@TEF01:~# javac -version

javac 11.0.3
```

build ONOS:

```
root@TEF01:~/onos# bazel build onos
INFO: Build option --host_javabase has changed, discarding analysis cache.
/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/548916f1c2f50851181f393ea08eaba4/external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/BUILD:419:14: Configurable attribute "actual" doesn't match this configuration: Could not find a JDK for host execution environment, please explicitly provide one using `--host_javabase.`
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.340s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded, 1737 targets configured)
Fetching @nodejs; fetching
```

I checked the BUILD file where the error appears:

```
alias(
name = "remote_jdk10",
actual = select(
    {
        "//src/conditions:darwin": "@remotejdk10_macos//:jdk",
        "//src/conditions:darwin_x86_64": "@remotejdk10_macos//:jdk",
        "//src/conditions:windows": "@remotejdk10_win//:jdk",
        "//src/conditions:linux_aarch64": "@remotejdk10_linux_aarch64//:jdk",
        "//src/conditions:linux_x86_64": "@remotejdk10_linux//:jdk",
    },
    no_match_error = "Could not find a JDK for host execution environment, please explicitly" +
                     " provide one using `--host_javabase.`",
),
visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
```

)

It seems that there's not ppc64le architecture configured in this file and I don't know what can I do. It also says jdk10 while I have jdk11 but there's other "remote_jdk11" with the same structure.
As you may see, I'm just a beginner so sorry if my question do not make sense or if I didnt explain myself correctly. Also, english is not my first language so sorry again.